# How to setup Launch4J XML

Tags: xml, launcher

This is how we currently start our application from a batch file. I'm trying to switch to launch4J but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to convert this to the required Launch4J XML file.

```
start MY_CUSTOM_JRE\javaw.exe -cp "./bin/*" org.company.browser.MY_Browser -arg1 -arg2 -arg3
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This worked out the best for me; over simplified compared to the readme. I believe arguments are allowed to go elsewhere but this worked out the best.

```
<launch4jConfig>
    <headerType>gui</headerType>
    <outfile>..\..\..\FINAL_APP_NAME.exe</outfile>
    <dontWrapJar>true</dontWrapJar>
    <errTitle>APP_NAME</errTitle>
    <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
    <icon>..\..\..\icons\icon.ico</icon>
    <classPath>
        <mainClass>org.company.jxbrowser.MY_Browser -arg1 -arg2 -arg3</mainClass>
        <cp>bin/*</cp>
    </classPath>
    <singleInstance>
        <mutexName>APP_NAME</mutexName>
    </singleInstance>
    <jre>
        <path>CUSTOM_JRE/</path>
    </jre>
    <messages>
        <startupErr>Startup Error</startupErr>
        <bundledJreErr>JRE Error</bundledJreErr>
        <jreVersionErr>JRE Version Error</jreVersionErr>
        <launcherErr>Launcher Error</launcherErr>
    </messages>
</launch4jConfig>
```